Were most people in pre-industrial societies in chronic pain?
My understanding is that, prior to the industrial revolution (and, indeed, for a fair while after), most people in Europe did not have a nutritionally balanced diet (if they were not calorifically malnourished, then a diet consisting overwhelmingly of grains would leave one nutritionally malnourished) and most of their work heavily involved manual labour.
This would seem to be a recipe for quite horrific long term health conditions - if not literal injuries from the manual labour which fail to properly heal, then having a chronically deficient diet would I imagine to lead to health issues in itself, of the sort which would lead to persistent pain.
So my question is: was this the case? Was the average person in, say, medieval Europe chronically unhealthy - specifically, chronically in pain?
I have tried to search for information regarding pre-industrial diets and malnourishment, but I've not been able to find anything confirming that the general belief that peasants were malnourished is even correct, but as far as I am aware this must be true given that the average male adult height was in England was only around 5ft5 from 1200-1600. If I need to be more specific about the place/time period being considered then that period in Western Europe would be what I am thinking of.

Subsistence agriculture is still a thing, and people cultivating most of their own food has been common in (rural) areas of Europe until recently. Those people, and preindustrial societies, aren't chronically malnourished, but in risk of food shortage in case of a series of bad harvests.

This doesn’t seem to be a view which is held unanimously: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2865862 This paper would seem to broadly support your view, but references other works which indicate “most of the early English population routinely lived at marginally adequate or outright substandard levels of nutrition”

Moreover there are numerous sources claiming nutrition worsened after the shift from hunter-gathering to agriculture, references for example here https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC6628670/#r3 so I feel the claim that in fact medieval peasants were by the by well fed outside of bad harvests (which, if occurring often enough, would still count as malnutrition) needs a bit more support?

Skeletons with arthritis at (relatively) young ages are common: "Examination of 400 Saxon, Romano-British, and mediaeval skeletons from seven archaeological excavations in the west of England showed an unexpectedly high incidence of osteoarthritis and osteophytosis [...] An exuberant form of large joint osteoarthritis was common" (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6797606/)

I think a diet of grains, legumes, cabbage, some fruit, some dairy and some small, occasional amount of meat (also in the form of broth made from sinew and bone) is not deficient at all. It is easy to romanticize, but many poor Americans eat much worse (and many Americans are in chronic pain!). Since only few people lived in cities, all of that could be self-produced.

@CarlosMartin Fascinating article! Poor ancestors! Causes for osteoarthritis include demanding physical labor (that would hit almost all of them) but also genetic predisposition. I cannot find anything specific nutritional but of course the occasional famine wouldn't help.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica About osteoarthritis and nutrition, a vitamin-deficient diet contributes to the disease. The most important vitamins are D, E, K and C. Since diseases like rickets and scurvy existed, we know people was lacking vitamins even when there wasn't a famine.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica many people would disagree. You're describing the current "standard diet" which is getting ever more criticism for being fundamentally deficient in micro nutrients and seriously overloaded in carbohydrates.

@jwenting If you are referring to the (American) actual standard diet I'd be amazed. For example, I think legumes and cabbage are not main staples (beans only in the Mexicanoid cuisine). Grains are only eaten (multi-)processed. There is a lot of meat. There is a lot of sugar, which hardly existed back then, etc. Maybe you refer to some recommended diet? In general, back then the food was also regional and therefore seasonal, which is pretty boring in winter, needs preparation (preserves, fruit storage etc.). That is far from any actual modern American diet.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica both the American and various European "standard diets" as defined by "health experts" are overloaded on grains and massively undervalue meat and dairy. In the Netherlands it's getting to the point where the responsible agency is openly advocating a strict vegan diet, though that's not made it into the official guidelines yet (they DO however advise hospitals to serve only vegan slop)

@jwenting Ah, you are referring to diet recommendations. I was not referring to that.

I'll answer specifically for medieval Western Europe and would be hesitant to generalize about pre-industrial societies transhistorically.
There's almost no question that bodily pain was more common, widespread and severe in an age where up to half the population in some areas died of bubonic plague. Even though life spans were shorter, painful conditions like osteoarthritis--associated with old age nowadays--were also surprisingly common. The fact that people underwent surgeries and painful treatments like trepanning without anesthesia is another clear illustration of how severe pain was a reality of life in ways that are almost unthinkable today. Treatment of severe pain with opium became common in Europe relatively late and there was no substitute with anything near that level of effectiveness.
An article about pain in the Middle Ages emphasizes how modern distinctions between chronic and acute pain or even physical versus spiritual pain seems to be completely foreign to the medieval worldview. The authors see the ubiquitous depictions of physical pain in Western religious art as evidence that pain was understood primarily as a shared rather than individual experience. So while we can expect many individuals did experience painful medical ailments that are rare today, we cannot assume the phenomenon of individuals experiencing chronic physical pain will be reported clearly in the historical record.

I know you're restricting your answer to Medieval Europe, but opium use was super widespread in antiquity.

People were also drunk a lot of the time. Beer was inexpensive and many men (and women) would drink to excess daily.

In addition to poor diets, most people were likely ill with something most of the time. Modern estimates for 'normal' body temperature are lower than previously accepted values due to people not carrying as many latent germs.

@cmw I suggest that in Europe the cost of opium (normally as laudanum) would have made it inaccessible to most of the population.

@Richard "small beer" was inexpensive and often preferred to water since the alcohol content killed at least some of the microorganisms. However I'm dubious that enough was drunk to impair workers' performance.

@Richard not true. The beer and wine they drank was lower in alcohol that current varieties and generally was consumed diluted as well.

@MarkMorganLloyd The alcohol content of even strong beer is inadequate for killing pathogens. The reason beer was safer to drink is that process of brewing beer involves boiling the water used for brewing.


if they were not calorically malnourished, then a diet consisting overwhelmingly of grains would leave one nutritionally malnourished

If they only ate white bread, this would have been true... But they didn't.
White bread was expensive, it takes a lot of work to separate the bran from the rest of the flour... So most peasants ate healthy whole grain bread.
Rye, Barley, Hempseed, and oats were cheaper then wheat so peasants diets included a lot of them.
Fancy whole grain bread was the cheap stuff of course this isn't all rosy, as the reason why white bread was valued is it was less likely to contain pebbles or sawdust as its much easier to see either of those in white flour then whole grain flour. (Millers didn't have a good reputation for honesty).
Greens were grown in the backyard and added to the diet in a variety of ways. A very common green was dandelions which are a rich source of potassium, vitamin A, C, K, E, folate, and small amounts of vitamin B.
Cabbage was another staple crop, as were leeks, beans, onions, pears, berries, apples,  peas...
One of the staple food during the middle ages was pulse, which was made with a grain (often oats) and vegetables:

This question sufferer from a misconception that was spread by the Victorian era, who were "much more enlightened/superior in everyway" then the 'dark ages' before the enlightenment.
It is actually the industrial societies <cough>Victorian era<cough> that suffered from malnutrition.
heck even during the Victorian era those poor unindustrialized farmers often had really good diets... Take the Irish, they ate potatoes, a lot of potatoes. While they sold their cash crops of wheat to England. The potato is a magical crop that is perfect for people with a very active lifestyle as it is calorie rich while containing a wide variety of vitamins, and takes very very little space to grow.  and so the Irish were healthier (until the potato famine) then the industrialized English, who ate wheat...
Everyone during the early industrialized era who were in unindustrialized places (IE the country side) had better health then the people were living in the industrialized society. Coal dust is bad for the lungs, and other people are the #1 source of disease, which early industrialized society had in abundance.
TLDR: No, medieval peasants didn't have a bad diet. The average peasant diet was significantly healthier than the average American diet.
Chronic malnutrition didn't kill peasants, it was war, famine (which causes acute Malnutrition I guess), and disease. Disease mostly killed the young (IE children) and the old. All 3 of which have been significantly reduced in modern society thanks to being significantly more peaceful, improved fertilization/the ability to water stuff, and modern medicine.
In fact the biggest thing that has reduced mortality in the world has been pre/post natal care for women and infants. As an extremely high infant/young child mortality rate (Whooping cough, mumps, scarlet fever etc..) is the reason why the average age during the medieval period was so low. TLDR: vaccines save lives

Now lets talk about chronic pain. What are the sources of chronic pain? According to my industrial safety classwork and Osha repetitive movement is the leading cause of chronic pain.
Now lets look at who does what:
Peasants do different motions throughout the day, seldom if every repeating the exact motion. They don't spend long periods of time sitting (which is a source of chronic pain). Didn't walk on concrete (source of repetive stress fractures). As a side note they also get in a lot of exercise which builds muscle, and muscle helps reduce chronic pain, in fact it is one of the things that doctors recommend to people to reduce chronic pain. Did they suffer from chronic pain as they got older? Sure, but so do we.
Want to know who does repetitive motion day in and day out? Factory workers in industrialized societies. Who would repeat the same motion day in, day out. Often with poor lighting, and bad air quality. Those people get repetitive motion injuries and suffer from a significantly higher amount of chronic pain. And also died at a much younger age...
TLDR: Sure they had chronic pain as they got older... But so do we.

In summary:
Did pre-industrial societies have chronic pain? Yes.
Was it caused by bad diet as a large percentage of modern chronic pain is? No. They had a healthier diet then the average American... Yes rictus/scurvy was a thing, but it was a disease of sailors and the Victorian era (early industrial society), not the pre-industrial society.
Was it caused by a long life of hard labor slowly grinding away the body? Yes. After the age of 30 there life gives you a free DLC every 5 years that causes things to hurt. This also happens during the modern era.
Could it be caused by acute injuries? Yes. Again, much like the modern era.
Was it as bad as during the early stages of our industrial society? Heck no. It was so much better.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
